# Angular production build once and deploy to multiple sites

Tags: angular

Angular 10+. Is it possible to achieve the below?

**Deploy the `dist` direclty to multiple sites, some under subsite/folder.**

- site1.com
- site2.com/portal
- site3.com/a/b

I prefer not to run `ng build` for each site to set each `base-href` explicitly.
(Currently it works if I just use ".")

**Avoid copying font/image from asset folder to the root**

Currently the build will duplicate the asset folder item at root (with hashed file name). And when index page loads, the files are not loaded from asset folder.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6599

Due to the subsites above, I can't set absolute path like `url("/asset")`. Neither can I import/set a path variable at runtime.

**Question**
What would be a good solution than building individual artifacts for each site?

Answer (score -1):

Following steps could help you as to *build once and deploy to multiple sites*.

At first add a configuration file, `app-config.json`, in the `src` folder and put the following.

```
{
    "url" : "http://site1.com"
}
```

Then make sure the configuration file is added to the `dist` folder. So, in the `angular.json` file you need to add the path to your configuration file to the assets array in the build configuration.

```
 ...
 "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/app-config.json"
            ],
 ...
```

Now create a configuration service with a call to get configuration data from `app-config.json` file.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {

  private configuration: AppConfig;

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { }

  setConfig(): Promise<AppConfig> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<AppConfig>('./app-config.json')
      .toPromise()
      .then(config => this.configuration = config);
  }

  readConfig(): AppConfig {
    return this.configuration;
  }
}
```

Then use `APP_INITIALIZER` to invoke the method retrieving configuration data. So `app.module.ts` will be like below.

```
const appInitializerFn = (configService: ConfigService) => {
  return () => {
    return configService.setConfig();
  };
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFn,
      multi: true,
      deps: [ConfigService]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now inject `ConfigService` into the `app.component.ts` to call `readConfig()` method.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  config: AppConfig;

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.config = this.configService.readConfig();
  }
}
```

and in `app.component.html` put the following just to check what was set in the configuration file.

```
<div>{{ config | json }}</div>
```

Hence your application will be capable to resolve configuration data at runtime.

Comment: The question is not about general configuration but `base-href` which is interpreted by Angular itself